# Static files with Django

Tags: python, django, static

I'm looking for the reason why Django can't serve my staticfiles but I can't find out.

First of all, my project structure :

```
- myProject
   |
   |----- myProject
   |        |- urls.py
   |        |- settings.py
   |        |- wsgi.py
   |
   |----- myApp 
   |        |
   |        |- #Usual files
   |        |- templates
   |               |- test.html
   |
   |----- static
   |        |
   |        |- myApp
   |        |    |- img
   |        |    |- css
   |        |    |- js
  ...      ...
```

My settings.py :

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'..'))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static'))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And when in test.html I call :

```
<img src="{% static 'myApp\img\tests-icon.png' %}" alt='Test'/>
```

It return a 404 error.

**Additional informations :**

- I'm using Windows
- I added `+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` to my `urls.py`
- I'm in debug mode
- I tried with slashes and backslashes for the url in the html file

The most surprising is that I installed Django debug toolbar and here's what my server said :

```
[02/Apr/2014 14:50:53] "GET /static/myApp/img/tests-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1718
[02/Apr/2014 14:50:53] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

He found `/static/debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js` but not `/static/myApp/img/tests-icon.png` ! I checked twice if the path was good and he is. I have no clue of the reason of the problem.

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Wow, did the Django people make static files and urlpatterns more complex than they needed to! They bite almost every single new developer. Check out http://bitsoul.com/2012/10/04/understanding-django-static-files-for-beginners/

Comment: It's a very good article ! 
I tried something else and, more surprising, 
`<img src="{% static 'django_toolbar\img\back.png' %}" alt='Test'/>` worked but `<img src="{% static 'myApp\img\back.png' %}"alt='Test'/>` doesn't ! I just copy-pasted the image ! Django is driving me crazy...

Comment: Change your static folder name from 'static' to something else, like 'res' and then update settings.py (or wherever you currently use 'static') and try again.

Comment: I found the error, I forgot to mention : 
`STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),)`. I though that it was understood thanks to the STATIC_URL but obviously not. 

Not very intuitive. Thanks jarmod for your help, your article helped me a lot !